# Почему не применяются стили в тег option в браузере Safari?

Tags: css, html5, safari

Всем привет.

Я делал список стран с флагами, которые я добавлял к каждому "option" через ":before", во всех браузерах все хорошо. Но в safari css стили не применяются. Проверял на 11 версии Safari. Подскажите пожалуйста почему так и как можно исправить.

[пример](https://repl.it/@Kvazarmw/selectSafiri)

Answer (score 0):

Это все потому, что `option` в принципе нормально до сих пор не обстиливаются и каждый браузер реализует какие-то возможности для этого сугубо на добровольных началах. Сафари этого не делает, вот и весь ответ. Этот недобраузер вообще должен умереть.